# Find 10th term of sequence based on sum of sequence and 8th term

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm in the midst of some pre-calculus practice questions and am having a tough time grasping this problem. I would like to know some ways of breaking it down, but not the solution itself. Layman terms preferable.

"The 8th term of an arithmetic sequence is 32.5 and the sum of the first 10 terms of the sequence is 187. What is the value of the 10th term of the sequence?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the first term be $a$ and the second $a+q$. Then the eighth is $$a+7q = 32.5$$ and the sum of the first 10 is $$a + a+q + a+2q + ... + a+9q = 10a + 45q = 187.$$

Now you can solve this system to find $a$ and $q$. The tenth term would be $a+9q$.

Answer (score 1):

See we have $32.5=a+7d$ now $187=\frac{10}{2}(a+a+7d+2d)$ so $37.4=a+2d+32.5$ so $a+2d=4.9$. Now i leave it to you you have two simultaneous solve them get $a,d$ then $a+9d$ is the term .